# Auto calculate sum for dynamically add and delete rows - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How calculate sum for dynamically add and delete rows, i can create some code but its working only add row, when i click the som wont calculating, I just need auto calculate sum when adding rows and deleting rows.

> When i delete rows the total sum not decrese.

Here is fiddle..

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/eya5v1wq/)**

Here is my snippet..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

   
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cashdeb' + counter + '" data-action="sumDebit" name="debit" placeholder="Debit amount"/></td>';
cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);

    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
    bindScript();
    counter++;
  });

  // delete function
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
  });

});

/* total */

$('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
        var val = parseFloat(e.value);
        if (!isNaN(val)) 
            total += val;
    });
    $('#totaldbt').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">

      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <th class="text-center">
            Debit*
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- total -->


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="cashTotal">
      <p class="tableTotal">Total:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="number" class="totaldeb" id="totaldbt" name="total" placeholder="Total Debit Amount" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `change` fires only when user changes a value of a form control element, it doesn't fire when you delete a row from a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change` event doesn't fires when you delete a row. I would suggest to have a separate function that evaluates the total and call it on change as well as on row delete.

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46fnv9ux/

```
$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  counter -= 1
  evaluateTotal()
});

$('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]', function() {
  evaluateTotal();
});


function evaluateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
    var val = parseFloat(e.value);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      total += val;
  });
  $('#totaldbt').val(total);
}
```

Comment: Sir, In this case How can do? i have one static column and this column dont have delete option. how can i do this case?? Please check this.. - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/6uyjncq2/

Comment: @Joe any problem with this solution? https://jsfiddle.net/46fnv9ux/

Comment: Its working sir, but i just need to keyup function. means when i start to enter value, automatically calculating the sum..

Comment: @Joe just change $('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]') to $('body').on('keyup', '[data-action="sumDebit"]') https://jsfiddle.net/3ych274o/

Comment: little optimization, direct decrement value when removing row, https://jsfiddle.net/3ych274o/1/

Answer (score 1):

just do the same thing when delete the row which you have done on add.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

   
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cashdeb' + counter + '" data-action="sumDebit" name="debit" placeholder="Debit amount"/></td>';
cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);

    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
    bindScript();
    counter++;
  });

  // delete function
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
     var total = 0;
    $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
        var val = parseFloat(e.value);
        if (!isNaN(val)) 
            total += val;
    });
    $('#totaldbt').val(total);
  });

});

/* total */

$('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
        var val = parseFloat(e.value);
        if (!isNaN(val)) 
            total += val;
    });
    $('#totaldbt').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">

      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <th class="text-center">
            Debit*
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- total -->


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="cashTotal">
      <p class="tableTotal">Total:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="number" class="totaldeb" id="totaldbt" name="total" placeholder="Total Debit Amount" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, In this case How can do? i have one static column and this column dont have delete option. how can i do this case?? Please check this.. - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/6uyjncq2/

Answer (score 1):

The delete button click event is not recalculating the total.

The answer by @Devis & Bilal will add all the values to find the sum. Instead you can just subtract the deleted row's value from total.

Modify the delete function as below, to subtract the deleted value from total.

```
  // delete function
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    counter -= 1
    var total = $('#totaldbt').val();
    var delVal = $(this).closest("tr").find('input').val();
    var val = parseFloat(delVal);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      total -= val;
    $('#totaldbt').val(total);
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  })
```

;

Comment: Sir, Please check this.. - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/bsk47ocu/ In this case How can do? i have one static column and this column dont have delete option. how can i do this case??

Answer (score 1):

I moved the calculation to a function calculateTotal and add an event for the delete button to recalculate total when any row is deleted:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";


    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cashdeb' + counter + '" data-action="sumDebit" name="debit" placeholder="Debit amount"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);

    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
    bindScript();
    counter++;
  });

  // delete function
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
  });

});

/* total */

$('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]', function(){
calculateTotal();
});

$(document).on( 'click', '.ibtnDel', function () {
 calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
    var val = parseFloat(e.value);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      total += val;
  });
  $('#totaldbt').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">

      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <th class="text-center">
            Debit*
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- total -->


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="cashTotal">
      <p class="tableTotal">Total:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <input type="number" class="totaldeb" id="totaldbt" name="total" placeholder="Total Debit Amount" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can do it in the following way:

```
$('body').on('change', '[data-action="sumDebit"]', function(){
    calculateTotal();

  $('#tab_logic').on( 'click', '.ibtnDel', function () {
    calculateTotal();
  });  
});

function calculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  console.log(total);
  $('[data-action="sumDebit"]').each(function(_i, e) {
    var val = parseFloat(e.value);
    if (!isNaN(val))
      total += val;
  });
  $('#totaldbt').val(total);
}
```

Comment: Sir, In this case How can do? i have one static column and this column dont have delete option. how can i do this case?? Please check this.. - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/6uyjncq2/